# Download files using puppeteer does not store file in /tmp folder of google cloud functions

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, pdf-generation, puppeteer, screenshot

I want to simulate download functionality for using puppeteer and the puppeteer script is running in cloud functions. I triggered the download button and set the download path to /tmp/ but when I read files from /tmp then my downloaded file is not showing up there. Sometime it randomly shows there.

```
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
    await page.goto(url);

    const downloadPath = `${os.tmpdir()}` + '/'; 
    await page._client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', {
        behavior: 'allow',
        downloadPath
    });

    await page.reload({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });

    const filename = `test-report.pdf`;
 
    await page.click('#screenshot'); //simulate download 
    await page.waitForTimeout(4000);

    const files = fs.readdirSync(downloadPath);
    console.log('Dir files ', files);
    const filePath = downloadPath + filename;
    const content = fs.readFileSync(filePath).toString("base64");

    await page.close();
```

this error comes:

> No file found in /tmp/report.pdf.

How to resolve that?

puppeteer version is ^10.0.0 and Node js version is 12

Answer (score 1):

This is what i tried and it seems to work:

`server.js`

```js
const os = require('os');
const fs = require('fs');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

exports.screenshot = async(req, res) => {

  // Asking for a URL to download 
  const url = req.query.url;
  if (!url) {
    return res.send('Please provide URL as GET parameter, for example: <a href="?url=https://example.com">?url=https://example.com</a>');
  }

  const downloadPath = `${os.tmpdir()}` + '/';
  const filename = 'example.pdf';
  const mypath = downloadPath + filename;

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
  const page = await browser.newPage()

  // Create PDF from URL
  await page.goto(url)
  await page.pdf({
    path: mypath,
    format: 'A4'
  })

  await page.close();
  await browser.close()

  // Check if file is in Cloud Function /tmp/
  if (fs.existsSync(mypath)) {
    console.log("exists:", mypath);
    res.sendStatus(200);
  } else {
    console.log("DOES NOT exist:", mypath);
    res.sendStatus(500);
  }
}
```

`package.json`

```
{
"name": "screenshot",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "Takes screenshot of the given URL, then checks if the download was successful",
"author": "",
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
},
"dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "os": "^0.1.1",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "puppeteer": "^1.10.0"
}
```

But please take note that Cloud functions /tmp/ folder is RAM so make sure all you store there are temporary files cause they will be deleted as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/using-temp-files)

Make sure to allocate enough memory, I ran into some memory limit issues while testing and I realised it was using around 400mib when downloading a medium size page.
I would recommend allocating at least 512mib, or 1Gib if you plan on downloading big pages.

Comment: Thanks @Lluis Muñoz. When I tried with generating pdf it was working, but here I am simulating download behaviour which downloads file in /tmp folder. but its not anyhow goes into /tmp. and u r right I already allocated 1 GB memory

Answer (score 0):

I would use, it worked for me in the past

> const file = fs.createWriteStream("/tmp/yourfile.yxz");

instead of

> const downloadPath = `${os.tmpdir()}` + '/';

Comment: Thanks @Chris32, could you explain and tweak code a little bit? It would be great, I am not getting it. Thanks again.